# How to show in Array.map() html files only?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this Array.map() to list files in cache:

```
<div data-offline></div>
    <script>
        if (navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
            caches.open('pages').then(function (cache) {
                cache.keys().then(function (keys) {
                    var offline = document.querySelector('[data-offline]');
                    offline.innerHTML =
                        '<ul>' +
                            keys.map(function(key) {
                                return '<li><a href="' + key.url + '">' + key.url + '</a></li>';
                            }).join('') +
                        '</ul>';
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

This is listing all kind of files in cache - html, js, css, images etc.

But I'd like to list html files only. There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way: In addition to `map`, which transforms  elements with the given function, you can use `filter`, which returns only those elements where the given function returns true.

So you would use `keys.map(f).filter(g).join('')`in your example, where f is your mapping function and g is your function that determines whether a file is of type html.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to exclude files before mapping them

**Updated Example**

```
"<ul>" +
keys
  .filter(function (key) {
    return !key.url.endsWith(".html");
  })
  .map(function (key) {
    return '<li><a href="' + key.url + '">' + key.url + "</a></li>";
  })
  .join("") +
"</ul>";
```

Comment: Ok, this EXCLUDES files. But what if I want to map / list on my page only .html files? And specifically only those inside a directory - e.g. /somedir/index.html/

Comment: Oops. Just change the logic inside that filter to your needs. Start with removing the ! and go from there.

Comment: I am trying, but unfortunately for me it is beyond my possibilities. Could you give me some clues? Thank you.